# How to wait a variable until it is no longer null in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am working on a project that requires me to wait until a variable is no longer null and then return it, it that possiable? For example, I have set a value `returnValue` in the start of the script like this

```js
let returnValue = null;
```

and I have something that would updates it

```js
      await page.on("request", async request => {
        const requestHeaders = request.headers(); //getting headers of your request
        // console.log(requestHeaders)
        const headers = JSON.stringify(requestHeaders)
        if (headers.includes("my-little-web-app")) {
          await fs.writeFileSync("./node_modules/ytcf/headers.json", JSON.stringify(requestHeaders, null, 4)),
            function (err, res) {
              if (err) throw err;
            };
            returnValue = headers
            console.log(headers);
            return headers
        }
```

And I have returned it

```js
return returnValue
```

The output: `null` (or `undefined`)

How can I export the value of `something-else` which is passed to `x`?
Thanks

Comment: Likely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321 - use `.then` or a callback

Comment: What do I do if I want to use callback?

Comment: Can't really say without more specific info of what you're dealing with - marginal psuedocode isn't quite enough

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question to give more info!